# Is there any software where we can see the content of a register when writing an assembly language program?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, assembly, x86, nasm

I'm learning assembly language but whenever I want to find an error in my code it becomes difficult.

Comment: Look for a debugger for your platform that understands assembly code.

Comment: Will visual studio code work?

Comment: See debugger usage tips at the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info